# How to remove the previous screen on the tab navigator - React Navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have the following tab navigator:

```
const RootTabNavigator: React.FC = () => (
  <RootTab.Navigator
    initialRouteName={GROUPS_STACK}
    tabBarOptions={rootTabNavigatorOptions}
  >
    <RootTab.Screen
      name={GROUPS_STACK}
      component={Groups}
      options={{ tabBarLabel: i18n.t("tabs.groups") }}
      listeners={tabBarGroupsListener}
    />

    <RootTab.Screen
      name={EVENTS_STACK}
      component={Events}
      options={{ tabBarLabel: i18n.t("tabs.events") }}
      listeners={tabBarEventsListener}
    />

    <RootTab.Screen
      name={INVITE_FRIENDS_STACK}
      component={InviteFriends}
      options={{ tabBarLabel: i18n.t("tabs.friends") }}
      listeners={tabBarFriendsListener}
    />
  </RootTab.Navigator>
);
```

[image]

And I would like to reset the stacks when pressing the tabs

For instance, when I press the `Groups` tab, it should reset the GroupsStack

How can I achieve that?

The approach that I took was to listen for the `tabPress` and then navigate to the respective navigator

```
<RootTab.Screen
  name={INVITE_FRIENDS_STACK}
  component={InviteFriends}
  options={{ tabBarLabel: i18n.t("tabs.friends") }}
  listeners={tabBarFriendsListener}
/>

/**
 * Navigation listener for the friends tab bar
 */
export const tabBarFriendsListener = ({
  navigation,
}: ListenersParameters): ScreenListeners<NavigationState, EventMapBase> => ({
  tabPress: () => {
    navigation.popToTop();

    navigation.navigate(INVITE_FRIENDS_SCREEN);
  },
});
```

The `popToTop` method takes back to the first screen in the stack

[image]

But I don't know to prevent this warning

Answer (score 0):

Consider using navigation events maybe you can use something like focus(This event is emitted when the screen comes into focus)
[This documentation link will help you understand better](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)

U can also try for using StackActions:
you need to: import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';
and then try using: navigation.dispatch(StackActions.popToTop())
use it for whatever stack you need to refresh

Comment: I updated the question above with the aproach that I tried. Also, the question that you linked doesn't seem to work with React Navigation v5

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/#parent-navigators-ui-is-rendered-on-top-of-child-navigator ...check this out too

Answer (score 0):

what about resetting the routes when pressing the Tab ?

```
export const tabBarFriendsListener = ({navigation,route}) => ({
  tabPress: (e) => {
     navigation.dispatch(CommonActions.reset({ index: 0, routes: [{ name: route.name}] })
  );
  },
});
```

Documentation: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions/#reset